# Populating fullcalendar event data using Java Struts

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, fullcalendar, struts-1

I've been following [this](http://rajboon.blogspot.com/2014/03/event-calendar-fullcalendar-event.html#comment-form) blog post.

However my calendar is not displaying. I would like to retrieve the data from the database, then output it using JSON (currently I've hardcoded test data in), then retrieve that JSON data using $.post() and populate the calendar with it.

My code -

**Action Mapping Definition**

```
<action path="/getCalendarEvents" 
        scope="request" 
        type="com.action.struts.AjaxAction"  
        validate="false"/>
```

**eventCalendar.jsp**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.post('getCalendarEvents.html?method=allEvents', {action: ''},
                function(data) {
                    var date = new Date();
                    var d = date.getDate();
                    var m = date.getMonth();
                    var y = date.getFullYear();
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                        theme: true,
                        header: {
                            left: 'prev,next today',
                            center: 'title',
                            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                        },
                        editable: true,
                        events: data
                    });

                }, "json"
                        );
            });
    </script>
```

**AjaxAction.java**

```
public class AjaxAction extends ActionForward{
     public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
                HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws Exception {
                        AjaxMoreUtil.getAllEvents(request, response);
                return null;
        }
}
```

**AjaxMoreUtil.java**

```
public class AjaxMoreUtil {
    public static void getAllEvents(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<CalendarDTO> allEventList = new ArrayList<CalendarDTO>();

        CalendarDTO c = new CalendarDTO();
        c.setId(1);
        c.setStart("2017-06-21");
        c.setEnd("2017-06-26");
        c.setTitle("Task in Progress"); 

        allEventList.add(c);

        CalendarDTO d = new CalendarDTO();
        d.setId(2);
        d.setStart("2017-06-01");
        d.setEnd("2017-06-10");
        d.setTitle("Task in Progress");

        allEventList.add(d);

        String json = new Gson().toJson(allEventList);
        System.out.println("json value " + json);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(json);
    }
}
```

When I run the application I get a 404 for the POST and nothing displays.

Comment: I can't say why you're getting a 404 for your request, because I don't know anything about struts. But in terms of the calendar setup you're going about it the wrong way round. You should declare the calendar at page load, and then the "events" property should be a function which runs your POST method. Your server should accept "start" and "end" parameters which it uses to filter the events by date. That way, when the calendar's view/date is changed, the calendar will automatically fetch events for the relevant dates. As it stands, you fetch them all at once, which is ineffficient...

Comment: ...and will get much more inefficient as time goes on and you have a large history of previous events, which probably people will usually not actually view. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/ and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/ for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this using a request variable.

In AjaxMoreUtil.java I put each event into an ArrayList.

```
List l = new ArrayList();
CalendarDTO c = new CalendarDTO();
c.setStart("2017-07-05");
c.setEnd("2017-07-08");
c.setTitle("event1"); 

l.add(c);
```

Then I converted that list into a JSON string using google's Gson JSON converter.

```
String resultSet = gson.toJson(l);

request.setAttribute("rs", resultSet);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/pages/Scheduler.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

In the .jsp I get the request variable and set it to a javascript var.

```
var rs = JSON.stringify(<%=rs%>);
```

And parse it into the calendar as a JSON string

```
events: JSON.parse(rs)
```

This displayed the information in the calendar correctly.